# Doesn't remove duplicate elements from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to take input from user in an array .And want to remove duplicate elements but the result is weird .I don't have to use uniq or any other ruby method.Here is my code

```
digits = []
digits = gets.chomp.to_i

k= digits & digits

puts k
```

```
input - 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 <br> 
Required output- 1 2 3 4<br>
Getting output 1
```

Comment: Please post result and any errors that you are getting.

Comment: What is the expected input and output?

Comment: okay I am posting input and  desired output

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: okay I have updated my question

Comment: `digits` is first an array. Next, `digits` equals an integer, say `4` (and the array `digits` is gone forever). Then you have `4 & 4 #=> 4`, since [Fixnum#&](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-26) is `Fixnum`'s "bitwise and" method.

Comment: Sorry sir maybe I am not able to express but i have clearly shown my input which i was taking but the output which i was getting was wrong .The output also I have mention in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets.chomp` returns string `"1 2 3 4 1 2 3"`

Then you call `to_i` on that string:

```
"1 2 3 4 1 2 3".to_i => 1
```

Consequentially `1 & 1 => 1`

You should do this:

```
digits = gets.chomp.split(' ').map(&:to_i)

k = digits & digits

puts k
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree with you however he said he doesn't want to use `uniq`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Can you clarify how `digits & digits` can contain duplicates? Intersection removes duplicates.